# Understand C source code, PHP implemention of rand

Tags: php, c, api, random

I have to made the premise that is a lot of time (almost a decade) that i don't use C as coding language, so my knowledge now is very limited.

I am trying to understand the C source code implementation of rand in the PHP framework.
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c

i have difficulties understanding a pice of the code :

```
/* {{{ php_mt_srand */
PHPAPI void php_mt_srand(uint32_t seed)
{
    /* Seed the generator with a simple uint32 */
    php_mt_initialize(seed, BG(state));
    php_mt_reload();

   /* Seed only once */
   BG(mt_rand_is_seeded) = 1;
}
```

Here i does not understand where BG came from (i can't find its definition in the source code).
Same for the variable 'state', i expect to find some global variable named accordlingly but i can't find any.

Comment: [here's](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9426c6e9679e60665f7ed95bccc1e8bc6ce74b2f/ext/standard/basic_functions.h#L127) the result of a very quick search for "define BG". Appears to fetch some global state variable.

Comment: question has very less to C, more on PHP C API

Comment: @JacekCz sorry for the mistake, i forgot to mention that i am also a PHP newby.
So when i saw C code i thought it's just regular C i'll dig a bit more on what is this PHP C API.
If you have any resource to share about i'll apreciate.
Thanks again for help and clarification.